# How do I open .msg and .eml files in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have made some attempts to open .msg and .eml files in swift 3 but all to no avail. I have used

```
UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: documentURL) as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil);
```

and

```
let url: URL! = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: documentURL);
            documentInterection = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url);
            documentInterection.name = url.lastPathComponent;
            documentInterection.delegate = self;
            documentInterection.presentOptionsMenu(from: backButton, animated: true);
```

None of the above opened the file like any other (.png, .doc, etc) would - with the help of let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame); ...

The former presents me with a UIWebView, which wouldn't open it. The latter pops up options but opens a blank new mail message if Outlook or iOS Mail client is selected.

I need some help on how to open .msg and .eml files in swift 3?

Pls note: the documentURL is a url of the .msg or .eml file to be opened, coming from an API.

Links I tried: [Open .msg and .eml files from iOS UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029632/open-msg-and-eml-files-from-ios-uiwebview)

Comment: What do you want to happen with these files? In both cases it looks like you want to tell some other app to open the file, but there's no app on the phone that knows how to read those files. What app do you want to open the files?

Comment: @TomHarrington I just want the user to be able to view the content, like he would with jpeg, pdf, etc. After viewing the file content, he can go back to the app to make necessary decisions. Presently, using the option 2 above shows the file as attachment in a new mail window, if Outlook or iOS mail client is chosen.

Comment: @Aweda Found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is

- You can't open a document and display the content unless either your app or some other app on the phone can parse the document.
- Neither your app nor any other app on your iPhone is capable of that, so
- Opening either fails or works in a way you don't want.

You can't make Mail or Outlook display the content. If they open it, they'll do whatever they think should be done with it. If they want to make it an attachment to a new message, that's their choice.

For many formats-- the PNGs, etc, that you mention-- there are lots of apps that will open and display them. For these specific formats, there aren't, at least on iOS. As a result you're stuck-- unless you implement support for these documents in your own app, or convince some other app developer to do so, you won't be able to display them.